# Why does the iris vanish when I set the origin of the outer sphere (cornea) to geometry?

Tags: mesh, texturing, geometry, origin

[image: iris, cornea and setting origin]

I'm trying to parent the iris to the cornea - but when I set the origin of the cornea (outer sphere) to geometry, the transparency disappears and so the iris is hidden. See below. Please help!

Blend file:
[image]

[image: cornea no transparency]

Comment: Unfortunately the screenshot doesn't show the node setup completely how the _Texture Coordinate_ node is used... I guess the texture mapping is in some way dependant on the object's geometry related to its origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change of the origin point has re-centered the object's *Texture Coordinate* normals, and the material for the cornea used these to determine where it should be transparent. The iris hasn't disappeared, it's just the eyeball that became opaque.

To restore it I did the following: select the cornea object (no matter which, since they use the same material), go to the *Shader Editor* to edit the material "Cornea".

In the *Mapping* node, set the *Location* for X to 0.5 m, leave Y and Z at 0 m. This should already make the iris visible but still the transparency is a little misplaced. So I repositioned the *Color Ramp* sliders as well, I've set the white one to 0.572 and the black one to 0.574, leave the interpolation at "Ease".

[image: eye repositioning]

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you so much Gordon - you made my day!! :D

Comment: @EmmaCulhane You're welcome. I've had a chat started in the other comments section, since longer discussions are advised to be avoided, just in case you needed more information.

Answer (score 0):

Although your screenshot doesn't show which output of the *Texture Coordinate* node is used, I guess it could be *Object*. If you use *Object*, the center point of the coordinates is at the object's origin point. In your first screenshot, the origin is seemingly outside the viewport and not visible (maybe that's why you want to center it to the *Geometry*).

But the position of the iris was adjusted to this (incorrect) origin point. If you now re-center it, the iris will change its position according to the new origin point.

Like in this example: I have a sphere with the origin point at the center by default. I use the *Texture Coordinate* > *Object* and separate the X, Y and Z values to display just the Z. The black color shows 0 at the center then changing to 1 at the top and at the bottom (this would normally be -1 but I've set it to absolute values).

[image: origin centered]

If I now set the origin point to the *3D cursor* which is above the center, then the  center or 0 of the Z coordinate moves up there as well. This is the reason why your iris disappears - you have it just the other way around. The misplaced origin holds the correct iris position, so switching to a centered origin removes the iris from the correct position.

[image: origin relocated]

Comment: Thank you Gordon! That makes sense, and yes, the output of the texture coordinate is set to object. Is there any way to rectify this do you know?

I'm trying to rig the eye you see, and it won't rotate with the origin set to the cross axis.

Comment: @EmmaCulhane I guess the face has a second eye? If there the origin point is correct I would duplicate it and put it in place of the incorrect one. Otherwise you have to reposition the iris after recentering. I just can't see in the screenshot how the iris is positioned right now... because _Mapping_ node values are all at 0, which should place everything in the center of the object if the origin is there. So I can only imagine that the way the iris is created puts it outside the center so it works with the incorrect origin. Could you upload your file here: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I will  try this :D.  I have uploaded the file now - called human_iris.blend

Comment: See file here: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=woV805sX" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/woV805sX/)

Comment: @EmmaCulhane Oh, that's completely different as I understood it. I misread your question - the iris is a separate object, not part of the eye mesh. So actually the iris is where it should be, it's just the transparent part of the eyeball has moved away because of changing the origin point. It would have been great to have the eye with the incorrect origin to better retrace where it is now, but of course you can completely build it new. I'll have a look.

Comment: @EmmaCulhane I've created a new answer, now it should work. I'll leave the other answer as example how the object's origin can influence the position of the _Texture Coordinate_ node.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128167/discussion-between-gordon-brinkmann-and-emma-culhane).